# Storing/updating deeply nested object array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of object by the below format

```
{
    id: 1,
    text: "Group 1",
    complete: 35,
    start: "2021-10-04T00:00:00",
    end: "2021-10-16T00:00:00",
    taskOwner: "test owner 10",
    wbsNumber: "1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        start: "2021-10-04T00:00:00",
        end: "2021-10-11T00:00:00",
        text: "Task 1",
        complete: 60,
        children: [
          {
            id: 1113,
            start: "2021-10-11T00:00:00",
            end: "2021-10-16T00:00:00",
            text: "Task New",
            complete: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

The children array can be nested N times. What is the best way to store/update this array in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

From the [official Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/):

> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents.

So if `N` could ever be expected to be larger than 100, then your Mongo driver would throw an error when you try to write.  But assuming `N` would not be near this threshhold, then you may work with your data as you would with any other data.

One workaround here might be to use the GridFS collection to store your massively nested JSON objects.  Your data would actually be stored as binary chunks.  However, realize that querying and updated data in GridFS will tend to be much slower than using BSON documents in a regular Mongo collection.  Before you go in the direction of GridFS, you might want to rethink your data model.

Comment: What if I store all items separately connecting them by a parent id?

Comment: @AkhilChandran Yeah...that's one way to go.  Then the "depth" of the child object could be represented by the ordinal position in the JSON array.  This of course would assume that you don't have a tree like structure, where one parent can have multiple children.